# Data structure similar to data.frames in R

Tags: c#, data-structures, datatable

I want to have a flexible data structure in C# that can work like dataframes in R and Python (or like a excel sheet).

The closest I could find was the native data table in C#.

Is there a better table structure that can hold data from different types in different columns?

Comment: There's a discussion item on dataframes against .net [on github](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26845) about this now. Would be great to get more demand for it on there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) in .NET.  It will allow you to define a set of typed columns (see the [`Columns` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columns.aspx)) as well as add a number of rows (see the [`Rows` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)).

Once you have that, you can easily access any row by:

- [Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwfe1t7z.aspx)
- [Column name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5.aspx)
- [The `DataColumn` instance representing the column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5akhx035.aspx)

However, consider the following: A [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) of [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) (from a projection from a query in LINQ) or strong types is probably just as good, if not better (no need for strings to get columns) depending on your need (if you *need* dynamic access dictated from user input, then using a `DataTable` would be better).

If you simply want a cross matrix of values, an anonymous type is an easy way to get a strongly-typed, compile-time-checked list of values, which has many more benefits than dynamically looking up the values.

Comment: I know this is over 4 *years* later... but similarly, a `Dictionary<T>` would also be good, where R's `colnames(df)` would be the same as C# Dictionary's `df.keys()`

Answer (score 2):

[Deedle](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle), an open-source project by Blue Mountain Capital might be worth looking at:

> Easy to use .NET library for data and time series manipulation and for
>   scientific programming

It is implemented in F# but they have worked on making it accessible from C# as well.

Development effort has gone a bit quiet in recent months however.