# How to have multiple R calls concurrently ,not sequentially, in a web application

Tags: .net, r, shiny, interop, r.net

I know that we can call R functionalities by Rscript or rdotnet in .Net. There are some nice explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021055/r-script-form-c-passing-arguments-running-script-retrieving-results/44122606#44122606), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485943/executing-r-script-programmatically?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025340/call-r-programming-language-from-net?noredirect=1&lq=1).

My question is:

How can we have multiple concurrent R calls in .Net?

I did the following test and found out that it is not possible to have them concurrent. It works sequentially. Any idea about how I can have them concurrent? Shall I switch to Shiny or Microsoft R server?

```
  string result=null; string filename = null;string args = null;
    int pp ;
    try
    {
        for (pp = 0; pp <= 20; pp++)
        {
              filename = uid+pp.ToString() + "." + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "." + DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text + dt + "." + DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
              args = filename + " " + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + " " + DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text;
            result = RScriptRunner.RunFromCmd(path + @"\rcode.r", @"D:\Programms\R-3.3.3\bin" + @"\rscript.exe", args);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

As suggested,

I changed it to

```
    try
    {
            Parallel.For(0, 20, (int pp) =>
            {
                filename = uid + pp.ToString() + "." + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "." + DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text + dt + "." + DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
                args = filename + " " + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + " " + DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text;

                result = resultFunction(path, pp, args);
            });
     }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
```

and it worked perfectly, all the expected outputs appeared almost instantly.

My concern is:

I intentionally forced the app to run in parallel. Shall I expect the same behavior in a web application with multiple online users (sessions)?

Comment: depends on both the server and requests...

Comment: No, we can not have them concurrent. R processes them as a queue (FIFO). That is the reason that I changed my question.

Comment: This limitation is only due to `RScriptRunner` implementation. `.NET` can start as many `.exe` files as long as they fit in your servers memory

Comment: Excellent point! Please let me try a parallel processing. I am going to call Rscript in parallel.

Comment: Please post your solution if you succeed

Comment: Of course, I will do.

Comment: Thanks, HubertL, very insightful comment. Much appreciated.